# this.setState refuses to run

Tags: reactjs, axios

here is the function that runs on Submit:

```
  signup(user = {}) {
    this.setState({loading: true});
     axios.post( '/users.json', { user })
     .then(response => {
       this.props.propagateSignIn(response.data)
       this.setState({
         error: null,
         newUserEmail: this.email.current.value,
         signedUp: true,
         loading: false
       }, console.log(this.state.signedUp, this.state.loading));
       })
     .catch(error => {
       if( error.response ){
         this.setState({
           error: error.response.data,
           loading: false
         });
       }
     })
  }
```

Everything runs except this:

```
   this.setState({
     error: null,
     newUserEmail: this.email.current.value,
     signedUp: true,
     loading: false
   }, console.log(this.state.signedUp, this.state.loading));
```

If I place a `console.log()` after it, it won't run either.

Why doesn't the state update ?

FYI here the function called in parent component when `this.props.propagateSignIn(response.data)` runs:

```
propagateSignIn(user) {
  this.getUser()
}
```

---

```
getUser(history = undefined) {
  axios.get("/users/get_current_user", {})
  .then(response => {
    if (response.data.user) {
      console.log('getUser:', response)
      this.setState({isReady: true,
                  ...response.data});
    } else {
      console.log("pas d'utilisateur connecté.")
      this.setState({
        user: null,
        isReady: true
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @sebink said When you create a ref, make sure it refers to the right component. In my case, `this.email.current.value,` actually refers to an input from another component as I split my Component into several ones and forgot to change some refs.

Answer (score 0):

well, actually you can try to wrap the console.log with a function because you need to provide a callback, not an "value". So the code could looks like:

```
this.setState({
   error: null,
   newUserEmail: this.email.current.value,
   signedUp: true,
   loading: false
  }, () => console.log(this.state.signedUp, this.state.loading));
})
```

In general placing a callback to the setState is not considered as best practice and you should do your callback logic inside of lifecycle methods for example in `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: hi @sebinq, thank you for your help; sorry if my explanation wasn't clear, but the problem isn't to get the callback function working: My problem is that this very particular `this.setState` doesn't get executed at all. My state does not update. I tried it with your code and the problem remains.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Don't you have `shouldComponentUpdate()` method implemented in your Component which is blocking re-render?

Comment: And what about `newUserEmail: this.email.current.value` are you sure that you have `email` initialized as a public variable of your component class?

Comment: omg thank youuuu @sebinq; I actually broke my code into multiple components and forgot to change `this.email.current.value` as it doesn't refers to the same component anymore.